# Do I have to keep a copy of all values put into views in my UIKit app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uiviewcontroller, ipod

I have a view controller with a view loaded from a NIB. As I understand it, the view can be unloaded from memory at any time by by controller. Say my app goes into the background, for example.

If I have values, such as text in a text field, those values will be lost when the view is unloaded. Or I might want to set those values before the view is loaded, in which case my outlets are not set and I am not able to do it yet.

Therefore, do I need to keep a shadow copy of all values in my user interface, so that I can re-set them in viewDidLoad: if the view gets unloaded and then loaded again?

Or am I doing things the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

In case of app going to background, implement methods to save and restore app. UIApplication will let you know when focus is going to and has changed in following UIApplicationDelegate methods:

```
– applicationDidBecomeActive:
– applicationWillResignActive:
– applicationDidEnterBackground:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

See help for more details.

Forgot about memory warnings... 
Solutions depend from case to case. In my experience, when it comes to the point when your visible view is removed to clear some memory, you don't want to implement recovery mechanism but test for memory leaks, observe memory allocations, optimize memory management  or rethink design.

Comment: Ok but that only works around one specific cause for a view being unloaded. What about every other reason for a view being unloaded? Including ones that perhaps aren't documented. I don't think UIViewController makes any guarantees about when a view is unloaded.

Comment: Well, UIViewController views are entirely managed by UIViewController. Look up View Controller Programming Guide for iOS to get clear picture. My suggestion is: don't worry. Even if you get into those situations, you'll be inclined to optimize memory usage, rather than worry about recovery. UIVIewController does tons of really tricky work for you so make sure you do the other part properly. The only other reason why view might get unloaded is you destroyed it by popping view controller from nav controller, for instance and you want new VC instance next time you push it. Don't keep references.

Comment: General rule is if you let UIViewController manage your view, well, let him manage it. When you're done with view, destroy UIViewController or remove view from superview. If you want custom view controller, check this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html